# How to write a dynamic text using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to accomplish something like this :

```
<?php $url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/img/picture.jpg'; ?>
<img src='<?php echo $url ?>' />
```

Only the problem is I want to accomplish this using javascript. Something like this

```
<script>url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/img/picture.jpg'</script>
<img src='<script>document.write(url)</script>' />
```

Of course it wouldn't work, but you got the idea. Any thought ?

Comment: It seems like you might be looking to do JavaScript templating. Mustache (http://mustache.github.com/) or Underscore (http://underscorejs.org/) are some of the libraries that you can look  into. This article: http://www.quora.com/JavaScript/What-is-the-best-JavaScript-templating-framework-and-why gives a good overview of what is out there.

Comment: Start by reading about [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) and [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML) basics and [how to work with the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_technologies_overview).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try - http://jsfiddle.net/m2Prh/

```
<img id="image" />​

<script>    
    var url = 'http://lorempixel.com/300/200';
    document.getElementById("image").src = url;​
</script>
```

Comment: Very obvious simple solution. Never though of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading jquery ,you can acesss every html element